# C: Using qsort to sort an array of pointers to an ADT (struct)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, qsort

I've been trying to use `qsort()` to sort an array of pointers of an ADT (named `SSET`), but I'm getting a weird result. Here's my function:

```
extern void sset_sort_sets(SSET *sets[], int n) {
    qsort(sets, n, sizeof(SSET *), sset_cmp);
}
```

In `sset_cmp()`, I put a statement to print out the `SSET`s it is comparing.

```
int sset_cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    SSET *pa = (SSET *) a;
    SSET *pb = (SSET *) b;

    printf("sset_cmp called:\n");
    printf("  a = "); sset_display(pa);
    printf("  b = "); sset_display(pb);
    printf("\n");

    // More stuff...
```

I created an array of two `SSET`s (in `main()`)

```
SSET *s[2];
int a[] = {-4, 0, 3, 3, 22};
int c[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
s[0] = sset_from_array(c, n); // { 1 2 3 4 5 }
s[1] = sset_from_array(a, n); // { -4 0 3 22 }

int i;
printf("Before sort:\n");
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    sset_display(s[i]);
printf("\n");

sset_sort_sets(s, 2);

printf("After sort\n");
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    sset_display(s[i]);
```

But here is what I get in the output:

```
Before sort:
  { 1 2 3 4 5 }
  { -4 0 3 22 }

sset_cmp called:
  a =   { -1589621936 -4 0 3 22 }
  b =   { -1589621568 }

After sort
  { 1 2 3 4 5 }
  { -4 0 3 22 }
```

I think I'm messing something up with the pointers in calling `qsort()`, but I'm not sure how.

I think I included all of the related code. Tell me if there's any other segments you need to find my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qsort()` passes a pointer to the array elements into the comparison function. So, if you have an array of `int`, the comparison function will receive `int *`.

You are attempting to sort an array of pointers to `SSET`, that is, an array of `SSET *`. Thus, the comparison function will receive pointers to pointers to `SSET` (so, `SSET **`).

So you need to change this:

```
SSET *pa = (SSET *) a;
SSET *pb = (SSET *) b;
```

To:

```
SSET *pa = *(SSET **) a;
SSET *pb = *(SSET **) b;
```

Also, it is usually a good idea not to hardcode a typename as the operand of `sizeof`. If the type changes, it is another place you'll have to update in the future, and you might make mistakes because you have to remember to use the correct type.

Consider changing this line:

```
qsort(sets, n, sizeof(SSET *), sset_cmp);
```

To:

```
qsort(sets, n, sizeof(sets[0]), sset_cmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SSET *pa = (SSET *) a;
```

looks wrong. `qsort` passes pointers to the elements to the comparison function. Your array elements are pointers, so your comparison function receives pointers to pointers:

```
SSET *pa = *(SSET **)a;
```